# How to get subscriptions of N instagram users by API python?

Tags: python, instagram-api

i want to take list of subscriptions(with names, not just number) of 100 users(for example) by API. Selenium not suits for me :( Any ideas?
I wanted to use instaloader first, but this solution have many problems. I tried Graph API, but didnt find solving my problem.